# Verification of a sequence of monotone increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\epsilon>0$ and $f_n:(0,\infty)\to(0,\infty)$ be defined by
$$
f_n(s)=n^{\epsilon}+\epsilon n^{\epsilon+1}(\frac{1}{n}-s),
$$
if $0<s\leq\frac{1}{n}$ and 
$$
f_{n}(s)=s^{-\epsilon},
$$
if $s>\frac{1}{n}$. Then $f_n$ is monotone increasing, i.e. for every fixed $s_0\in(0,\infty)$ one has $f_{n+1}(s_0)\geq f_n(s_0)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I tried to prove in the following way step by step:

Case 1. Let $s_0>\frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{n+1}$. Then
$$
f_{n+1}(s_0)=s_0^{-\epsilon}=f_n(s_0).
$$
Hence $$f_{n+1}(s_0)-f_n(s_0)=0.$$
Case 2. Let $\frac{1}{n+1}<s_0<\frac{1}{n}$. Then
$$
f_{n+1}(s_0)=s_0^{-\epsilon},
$$
and
$$
f_n(s_0)=n^{\epsilon}+\epsilon n^{\epsilon+1}(\frac{1}{n}-s).
$$
Case 3. Let $0<s_0\leq\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n}$. Then
$$
f_{n+1}(s_0)=(n+1)^{\epsilon}+\epsilon(n+1)^{\epsilon+1}(\frac{1}{n+1}-s_0)
$$
and
$$
f_n(s_0)=n^{\epsilon}+\epsilon n^{\epsilon+1}(\frac{1}{n}-s).
$$

In case 1, we have $f_{n+1}(s_0)-f_n(s_0)=0\geq 0$. But in both Case 2 and Case 3, I am unable to prove $f_{n+1}(s_0)-f_n(s_0)\geq 0$.

Can somebody please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean f instead of H?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for correcting the typo. I have edited it.

Comment: Did u get any hint? @marty cohen

Comment: No. Too busy on other things.

Comment: Please have a look if you find some time. Thanks.